# Can alias templates have default template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, alias

The following code is very short, but causes different compilers to behave [disagree](https://godbolt.org/z/e7T7WY):

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T = int, typename... Ts>
using tpl = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;

tpl x; // I would assume this should be std::tuple<int>
```

Clang and MSVC say that template argument deduction doesn't work for alias templates, ICC says that template arguments are missing, while GCC has an `internal compiler error`. I would normaly consider that an indication that alias templates do not undergo deduction - especially that according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Alias_templates) they don't (which I am aware is not an official resource and just a *reference*) - but I would like to be sure.

Is this code really ill-formed or are alias template default template arguments simply not yet implemented in these compilers? I thought that they were added in C++17 or C++20.

Comment: Default template parametrs work - you should put `tpl<> x`. This is not the same as template type deduction which in fact doesn't exist for aliases.

Comment: @bloody They have been added for C++20 (P1814R0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### C++20 introduces CTAD for alias templates

An alias template may indeed have default template arguments, and it is legal to have default template arguments to template parameters that are followed by a template parameter pack, as per [[temp.param]/14](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#14.sentence-1):

> If a template-parameter of a class template, variable template, or alias template has a default template-argument, each subsequent template-parameter shall either have a default template-argument supplied or be a template parameter pack. [...]

The default template argument is a red herring, however, and the key here is whether class template argument deduction is valid or not for alias templates, and we may minimize your example to the following one:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
using tpl = std::tuple<T>;

tpl x{1};  // should deduce tpl<int> in C++20
  // Clang: error
  // GCC 9.3: error
  // GCC 10.1: ICE / internal compiler error
```

As per [P1814R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1814r0.html)<sup>(1)</sup>, which was accepted for C++20, the minimal example above is indeed legal, but Clang is [yet to implement](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) P1814R0, explaining why Clang rejects it. GCC, on the other hand, lists P1814R0 as [implemented for GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), meaning it should accept it for C++20.

<sub>(1) As per C++20 and [P1814R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1814r0.html) (*Wording for Class Template Argument Deduction for Alias Templates*), (/wording for original proposal [P1021R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1021r4.html)) CTAD is applicable also for alias templates, whilst however not allowing explicit deduction guides for them.</sub>

In C++17 you need to include the template argument list (even if it's empty) when using alias templates - there is no equivalent to class template argument deduction for alias templates in C++17:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T = int, typename... Ts>
using tpl = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;

tpl<> x; // OK in GCC and Clang
```

---

An ICE (internal compiler error) is always a bug, no matter if the code is ill-formed or well-formed, and as noted above GCC emits an ICE only for 10.1 and later, whereas it yields an error for previous releases.

Thus, GCC apparently have a ICE regression for 10.1 (which was suspiciously listed as the target when CTAD for alias templates were implemented). It is at the very least related to the following bug report:

- [Bug 96199 - [10/11 Regression] internal compiler error: in tsubst_copy with CTAD for alias templates](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96199)

Which however is listed as resolved, whereas your example still yields an ICE for a GCC trunk that includes the fix to 96199.

---

We may finally note that GCC successfully applies CTAD for the alias template where we only use a template parameter pack:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Ts>
using tpl = std::tuple<Ts...>;

tpl x{1}; // OK
```

but that if we replace `std::tuple` by `std::vector` in the minimal example:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
using vec = std::vector<T>;

vec x{{1}}; // GCC 10.1: ICE
```

we get another kind of ICE for GCC 10.1 (and forward), whereas adding a default template argument and replacing the braced-direct-initialization with default-initialization is accepted.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T = int>
using vec = std::vector<T>;

vec x;  // GCC 10.1: OK
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems though that this code compiles under GCC: 
`
template <typename T = int>
using vec = std::vector<T>;

vec x;` However with `std::tuple` it doesn't. Could this be a GCC bug?

Comment: @enthusiastic_3d_graphics_pr... GCC seems to have some kind of ICE bug here (see my updated answer); afaict even using a default template argument in the alias template and attempting CTAD for a deault-initialized variable should be viable (as the default template arguments are brought over to the invented function templates that CTAD use for deduction).